# Send POST request from Tornado to Django rest framework, real time chat application

Tags: python, django, rest, chat, tornado

I'm working on a chat app for mobile that needs to handle 10k+ messages/s.
I want to save every message to database by sending post requests from tornado to django rest. 
I don't know which is the best way to write my post request not to slow down the server.

This is my function:

```
def SaveToDatabase(endpoint, data):
    #data= {"user_id": msg['username'], "room_id": 1, "message": msg['payload']}
    req = urllib2.Request(endpoint)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Tornado is an asynchronous server, so you should send that post request in asynchronous way also. `urllib2` will block whole worker waiting for response, that worker won't take any other requests until post is done. You should use `httpclient` from tornado:

```
request = httpclient.HTTPRequest(endpoint, body=json.dumps(data), method="POST", headers={"content-type": "application/json"})
response = yield http_client.fetch(request)
print response
```

All that code should be inside coroutine. You can also use [AsyncHTTPClient](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient) that will call your callback when request is finished instead of creating proper coroutine for that.